# Arduino : HC-06 Module receiving wrong data?

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino

I'm using a HC-06 Bluetooth Module to control my Arduino Uno, I want to implement a simple program that can turn On and Off an LED.

Code -

```
char val;

 void setup()
 {
 pinMode(13, OUTPUT); 
 Serial.begin(9600);

 Serial.println("Ready");
 }
 void loop()
 {

  if(Serial.available()){

    val = Serial.read();
    Serial.println(val);
   // digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
  }

  if (val=='1'){
    digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
  }
  else if(val=='2'){
    digitalWrite(13,LOW);
  }

  delay(100);

}
```

I used different apps to send data to the module, from my phone, but when I send 1 and 2 they are displayed in the Serial monitor as " ÿ " and the LED does not turn ON probably because the data does not match 1 or 2 , I have tried changing the baud rates as suggested by many forums and answers, still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the delay after you read the data, in order to give time arduino to process the infomration (it could be just 10ms):

```
 void setup()
 {
 pinMode(13, OUTPUT); 
 Serial.begin(9600);

 Serial.println("Ready");
 }
 void loop()
 {

  if(Serial.available()){

    val = Serial.read();
    Serial.println(val);
    delay(10);
   // digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
  }

  if (val=='1'){
    digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
  }
  else if(val=='2'){
    digitalWrite(13,LOW);
  }

  delay(100);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the main issue is that you are printing `Ready` in setup. Due to this the `Serial.available()` the function has some value already. In the following code, I'm waiting for input on the serial line. As soon as serial have some input the while loop will break and the code will proceed. After getting first char from the input I'm just flushing any unnecessary content if available. If this doesn't solve your problem then let me know.

```
char val;

void setup() {
    pinMode(13, OUTPUT); 
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {

    while(Serial.available() <= 0);

    if(Serial.available()) {
        val = Serial.read();

        //Flush any excess input
        while(Serial.available()) {
            Serial.read();
        }

        Serial.println(val);

        if (val=='1'){
            digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
        }
        else if(val=='2'){
            digitalWrite(13,LOW);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried this code, Doesn't work :/, same result. Thank you

Comment: @AnjukaKoralage What baudrate do you set on the computer doesn't matter on HC06 module serial output. You have to set exactly the same baudrate on the Arduino as on the HC06 (that one set by AT command)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by setting the baud rate of the BT module to 38400, it depends on the type of the module you're using, some may work at different baud rates.

```
BTSerial.begin(38400);
```